# gcloud docker -- push results in login attempt failed with 404

Tags: docker, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I am trying to push a docker image to Google's container registry but keep getting a error about Docker login having failed. I run

```
gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/<my-project-id>/test-image
```

I get back

```
ERROR: Docker CLI operation failed:

Error response from daemon: login attempt to 
https://appengine.gcr.io/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found

ERROR: (gcloud.docker) Docker login failed.
```

Other gcloud operations that don't go through docker work. I can for example create a cluster via `gcloud container clusters create my-cluster`.

I did play around with a local registry today, not sure if that might have broken things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You just need to disable storing docker credentials on macOS keychain on preferences of Docker for Mac.

Comment: And since it's worth a killoword: [a screenshot of how to implement](http://imgur.com/a/665d6)

Comment: `gcloud docker` commands were working fine for me all last night. Then sometime today (7/18/17) I did a docker client update and the commands stopped working. Search let me here and this answer fixed the issue.

Comment: you saved my day! Why would anyone rollout such updates?.. Bizzare.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**: It seems my approach works only *temporarily*. Thanks to @hamx0r for posting a screenshot of how to apply the long-term fix.

---

Disable storing docker credentials on mac os x keychain by removing this entry from your `~/.docker/config.json` file.

```
    "credsStore": "osxkeychain",
```

In my case, I had no additional configuration (I wasn't logged in), so I just blanked the entire file.

Comment: this worked to fix it for me as of July 11, 2017

Comment: It seems my approach works only temporarily. Thanks to @hamx0r for posting a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/665d6) of how to apply the long-term fix.

Answer (score 5):

An update should be available in `Google Cloud SDK` `v164.0.0` to fix this issue, sorry for the trouble.

Now would probably be a good time to advertise the newest, hottest authentication method in town:
[`docker-credential-gcr`](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#docker_credential_helper)

Edit: [`v164.0.0` has been released](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#16400_2017-07-26):

**Breaking Changes**

- Removed `appengine.gcr.io` from the list of default repositories that `gcloud docker` authenticates for.

Comment: Update helped in my case

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I was using Docker for Mac from Edge channel (see difference https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/). After switching to Stable (BEWARE, you lose all your images, containers, volumes, configs), I can push images to Google Container Registry again.

Comment: As of June 28th, the stable branch has this issue as well. This answer is no longer correct, alas.